# webRTC check if stun server is beeing used

Tags: javascript, webrtc, stun, simplewebrtc

I decided to create my own STUN server to use it together with the following  JS library https://simplewebrtc.com.

I decided to use this: http://www.stunprotocol.org/

I have followed the instructions and it seems like the server is running. 
The command `sudo lsof -i:3478` (3478 is the default port) outputs this:

```
stunserve 12856 user    3u  IPv4 232305      0t0  UDP *:3478
```

I have also modified the JS library to use my server according to this instructions: https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC (`peerConnectionconfig`).

```
peerConnectionConfig:{iceServers:[{urls:"stun:myServerHost:3478"}]}
```

But when I use tcpdump to capture the traffic on the server nothing is captured like the server is not used. Which server is then used if this one is configured?

Comment: You can run stuntman with the `--verbosity 4` command line parameter to see all server traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the configuration is like this:

```
{ iceServers: [ 
    {
        "url": "stun:your.stun.server"
        , "username": "user"
        , "credential": "password"
    }
]}
```

Credentials are optional. And you can use https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/ to test your stun server.

Comment: Testing the server I don't get it, no mather what I type as a server, some candidates are always returned

Comment: Compare with and without your server, the number of candidates or select 'relay' instead of 'all'.

Comment: Actually, `url` [got renamed to](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCIceServer) `urls`.

Comment: I guess I am setting the configuration the wrong way.  What would be the correct way?

This is not workig:
webrtc.config.peerConnectionConfig = .......